# How to use Ember.js {{action}} in Handlebars.js templates on top of Jade

Tags: node.js, express, ember.js, pug, handlebars.js

I'm using Ember.js and Handlebars.js for a project I'm working on at the moment. Server-side is Node.js + express and I make use of the Jade templating engine.

Now, whenever I want to tie actions to DOM elements, I use the {{action}} attribute of Ember.js. Currently, this is how my code looks in Jade:

```
script(type='text/x-handlebars', data-template-name='frontpage')
  div.logo(''='{{action goToFrontpage}}')
```

The above *does* work, however, the `''='{{action goToFrontpage}}'` part seems somewhat hackish.

Is there any other way of doing this? Perhaps a best-practice when combining Ember.js, Handlebars.js, and Jade?

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that perhaps using regular HTML in Jade is the way to go. Thus, the answer would be to write `<div {{action GoToFrontpage}} class="logo"></div>` since Jade also supports regular HTML.

Comment: Add this comment as an answer and accept it then :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sometimes it's better to just use html in Jade.

```
<div {{action GoToFrontpage}} class="logo"></div>
```

An other example I see a lot is the strong tag.

```
 .stuff
   | This is an
   strong important
   | message.
```

You can write this

```
 .stuff This is an <strong>important</strong> message.
```

I find the second a lot more readable and concise.